# Writing test cases for sqlalchemy models in pyramid

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm building an application with pyramid and sqlalchemy. I'm trying to work as clean as possible, so right now I'm just writing models and try to do solid test cases for them. Ideally I'd expect them to accept a database configuration to work with (since different DB systems do differ; for the application I'll be working with mysql), but even a decent way of doing it with sqlite would help.

The page [Adding Tests](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/tests.html) in the SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch Wiki Tutorial somehow is not too helpful on that part, as it says

> To test the model class Page we'll add a new PageModelTests class to our tests.py file that was generated as part of the alchemy scaffold.

but then it fails to mention said `PageModelTests` class ever again.

Does anyone know a helpful tutorial on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just presented on testing SQLAlchemy models in Pyramid in my talk [Building the App](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/library.html#buildingtheapp).   Two approaches are presented, the "transactional" and the "mock" style.  For a demonstration of these methods as well as a comparison of techniques, see the example app at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/pycon2014_atmcraft/:

[fixtures](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/pycon2014_atmcraft/src/a6d96575bc497ce0c952bb81db9c05d054c98bb5/atmcraft/tests/__init__.py?at=master)

[transactional testing examples](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/pycon2014_atmcraft/src/a6d96575bc497ce0c952bb81db9c05d054c98bb5/atmcraft/tests/test_views_transactional.py?at=master)

[mock testing examples](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/pycon2014_atmcraft/src/a6d96575bc497ce0c952bb81db9c05d054c98bb5/atmcraft/tests/test_views_mockdb.py?at=master)

Comment: Wow, that really looks promising. Two concepts explained and compared, and that on exactly the tools I want to use, thanks. I'll take a deep look into that, as soon as I can.

Comment: Yeah, that helps. Took me a while to put it to a concept that I'm contempt with. Your video (and another on sqlalchemy introduction) where very enlightening (and atmcraft ftw, btw). Thanks for your works, I like the ground principles of SQLA (and pyramid).